# Activity has leaked window DecorView@92f9f38[] that was originally added here error

Tags: android, google-maps

I wrote a code to load near by `hospitals`, `restaurants` and `schools` in Google maps. I'm using these depedencies: `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'` and `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'`. I'm using Gradle 3.0.0. When I run my code, I get this error:

```
Activity has leaked window DecorView@92f9f38[] that was originally added here
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:417)
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:316)
   at com.dell.spacestemp.ui.Activities.NearByActivity.CheckGooglePlayServices(NearByActivity.java:81)
   at com.dell.spacestemp.ui.Activities.NearByActivity.onCreate(NearByActivity.java:61)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

That error happens in this code block:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }

        //Check if Google Play Services Available or not
        if (!CheckGooglePlayServices()) {
            Log.d("onCreate", "Finishing test case since Google Play Services are not available");
            finish();
        }
        else {
            Log.d("onCreate","Google Play Services available.");
        }

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }



private boolean CheckGooglePlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
                googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                        0).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

How can I fix it? What is causing it? Why is it happening?

Comment: i think you're showing a dialog and after that you're using map fragment. First you must close the dialog.

Comment: I'm not showing any dialog here...

Comment: Post your `onMapReady()` implementation please.

Comment: What does this line work ? `googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                        0).show();`

Comment: Actually my code was correct. When I ran it in emulator, I got error as given in question. When I ran it in local device, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Place the fragment transaction code in the else part of

```
if (!CheckGooglePlayServices()) {
 ......
}
else {
    Log.d("onCreate","Google Play Services available.");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Or you can try ;

```
if(!((Activity)YourActivity.this).isFinishing()) {
     SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
     mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

The code mentioned below uses separated thread for execution ..

```
  int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

> This was happening because your activity is finishing during the fragment transaction !!

Comment: Actually my code was correct. When I ran it in emulator, I got error as given in question. When I ran it in local device, it worked perfectly.

Comment: This code will work on both emulator and device..! @AjayKulkarni

Comment: I think that it wouldn't work because my emulator doesn't support google maps and play services

Answer (score 0):

I think your code trying to get context after destroying the activity

Comment: Actually my code was correct. When I ran it in emulator, I got error as given in question. When I ran it in local device, it worked perfectly.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni make sure your emulator supports google maps and has play services.